# MySQL to JPQL Inner Join

Tags: mysql, sql, jpql

I'm new to JPQL and struggling a bit to translate my SQL to JPQL. I have a simple query which works on MYSQL:

```
SELECT askorder.price, bidorder.price from OrderBook JOIN askorder 
ON OrderBook.ASKORDERID_ORDERID = askorder.ORDERID
JOIN bidorder ON OrderBook.BIDORDERID_ORDERID = bidorder.ORDERID
WHERE askorder.ORDERID = 2;
```

I've attempted to translate this to JPQL but I'm sure it's wrong. Specifically I think it may be the ON keyword, I'm not sure how to translate that to JPQL:

```
@NamedQuery(
    name="findOrderBooksPrices",
    query="SELECT ao.price, bo.price from OrderBook bo, OrderBook ao" +
    "INNER JOIN ao ON bo.ASKORDERID_ORDERID = ao.ORDERID " + 
    "INNER JOIN bo ON OrderBook.BIDORDERID_ORDERID = bo.ORDERID " +
    "WHERE ao.ORDERID = :askOrderId"
)
```

The error I get is:

```
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7158] (Eclipse Persistence
Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): 
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Error encountered when building the @NamedQuery
[findOrderBooksPrices] from entity class [class  
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.queries.
NamedQueryMetadata].Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.NullExpression cannot be cast to 
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.IdentificationVariable. Please
see server.log for more details.
```

I'd like it to return the prices from each order table after submitting the order id.

Thanks for looking.
Cheers,
Zerb

Comment: why do yuo call the table `ao` here `INNER JOIN ao ON`  but in core mysql you call the table `JOIN askorder ON`  so what is real table name?

Comment: The real table name is askorder. I just got my syntax confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess:

```
 query="SELECT ao.price, bo.price FROM OrderBook " +
    "INNER JOIN askorder ao " + 
    "INNER JOIN bidorder bo " +
    "WHERE ao.ORDERID = :askOrderId"
```

Comment: Thanks Alex but I still get the same exception with that query, but I think it's more correct than what I had.

Comment: @zobbo so try to comment all the line except first one `query="SELECT ao.price, bo.price FROM OrderBook "`. if it works uncomment next line. and so on line by line.

Comment: `SELECT bo.price FROM OrderBook bo` works, the next line `INNER JOIN AskOrder ao ON OrderBook.ASKORDERID_ORDERID = ao.ORDERID`  fails. I edited the first line since the original failed also. Just trying to work out that second line now.

Comment: @zobbo I just checked what is `jpql` :-) so it has completely different syntax than `mysql`. If I got it correctly you should just `"INNER JOIN askorder ao "` in second line. If your database schema has PK-FK relation there it will link tables automatically.

Comment: Alex thanks for that. Yeah I noticed it didn't have an ON keyword so that explains it. So far I have this and it's compiling, though whether it's returning what I'm looking for is another matter. `name="findOrderBooksPrices",
     query="SELECT bo.price, ao.price FROM OrderBook ob " +
        "INNER JOIN AskOrder ao " + 
        "INNER JOIN BidOrder bo " +
        "WHERE ao.orderId = :askOrderId"`